# Can the variables of $y = A + B \mathrm{e}^{C t}$ be solved analytically given 3 sets of points?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Given the non-linear equation  $y = A + B \mathrm{e}^{C t}$ and 3 sets of points: ($y_1$, $t_1$), ($y_2$, $t_2$), ($y_3$, $t_3$), can the variables $A$, $B$, and $C$ be calculated analytically?

\begin{align*}
    y_1 = A + B \mathrm{e}^{C t_1} \\
    y_2 = A + B \mathrm{e}^{C t_2} \\
    y_3 = A + B \mathrm{e}^{C t_3}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    y_1 - y_2 = B \mathrm{e}^{C t_1} - B \mathrm{e}^{C t_2} \\
    y_2 - y_3 = B \mathrm{e}^{C t_2} - B \mathrm{e}^{C t_3}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{y_1 - y_2}{y_2 - y_3} = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{C t_1} - \mathrm{e}^{C t_2}}{\mathrm{e}^{C t_2} - \mathrm{e}^{C t_3}}
\end{align*}

This is where I am stuck. Without using approximations, I can't reduce this function to determine the variable $C$. Is this possible?

Comment: try using trig functions to simplify this further.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I've tried using logs and trig functions, but the expansion becomes very messy. Are you suggesting that trig functions *may* work, or are you certain?

Comment: My bad, I misread the subscripts on the $t$'s, I thought they agreed on the numerator and denominator (which would make this the ratio of two hyperbolic sines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general case, as written, you cannot extract $C$ from the third equation since it is highly transcendental. The only solution would be a numerical method such as Newton which would work without any problem provided a reasonable guess; a plot of the function (the third equation) as a function of $C$ will allow you to locate the root and start iterating from this value.

However, there are cases where this is feasible. The simplest I found corresponds to $t_2=2t_1$ and $t_3=3t_1$. For such a case, simplifying the rhs, you should arrive to $$C=\frac{\log \left(\frac{{y_2}-{y_3}}{{y_1}-{y_2}}\right)}{{t_1}}$$ Similarly, if $t_2=2t_1$ and
 $t_3=4t_1$, you should arrive to  $$C=\frac{\log \left(\frac{-\sqrt{{y_1}-{y_2}} \sqrt{{y_1}+3 {y_2}-4
   {y_3}}-{y_1}+{y_2}}{2 ({y_1}-{y_2})}\right)}{{t_1}}$$

Comment: Thanks Claude! I guess I will just have to use numerical methods.

Comment: @William. In the most general case where there is no specific relation between $t_1$,$t_2$ and $t_3$, this is the only way. Just solve for $C$ the last equation. If you need more for the solution, just post. Cheers.